# click a textblock without selecting the parent listview item

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows store application with `C#` and `XAML`. I am using a `ListView` to display the collection of data.

Inside the `ListView` I have a data template which has grids and a TextBlock in the grid. I want to tap/click the TextBlock and give action without selecting the parent `ListView` item as I already have event to handle the selected `ListView` item. I don't want both to overlap.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to select the `ListViewItem` when tapping one part of it, but not the `TextBlock`? If this is the case, in the `TextBlock`'s `Tapped` event add `e.Handled = true;`. This should make it so that it isn't further routed up to the parent `ListView`.

The other thing you can do (which will likely be a more general solution to whatever you want to do with your ListViewItems) is to *not* use thing `SelectionChanged` event and instead handle everything with `ItemClick`. You can then deduce whether the `OriginalSource` of the event is indeed your `TextBlock`. Then, if it's not the `TextBlock`, change the parent `ListView`'s `SelectedItem`.

An example for chceking the OriginalSource

```
public static void ItemClickEvent(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)
        DoNothingOrMaybeTextBlockEvent();
    else
    {
        ListView.SelectedItem = e.ClickedItem;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: Added some example code for the OriginalSource check

Comment: I used ItemClick for listview , not SelectionChanged. When I tap the textblock which is inside the listview item, The listview is also getting clicked, which i want to avoid. I just want the textblock to be clicked.

Comment: Check the `OriginalSource` of the `ItemClickEventArgs` and see if it's your `TextBlock`.

Comment: Yes,the OriginalSource is the TextBlock.

Comment: I found a solution, to remove the clickevent for the parent the listview ,which I found is unnecessary anyway. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution!